# 'float' object has no attribute 'tanh'

Tags: python

```
  parameters = nn_model(X, Y, n_h = 4, num_iterations=10000, print_cost=True)
  plot_decision_boundary(lambda x: predict(parameters, x.T), X, Y)
  plt.title("Decision Boundary for hidden layer size " + str(4))
```

I am getting an error while running this code

Comment: Hi there and welcome to SO. Please give us some context to your question. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints. It's a good start to give some data, make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and give an example of your desired output.

Comment: # Implement Forward Propagation to calculate A2 (probabilities)
    ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 4 lines of code)
    Z1 = np.dot(W1, X) + b1
    A1 = np.tanh(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + b2
    A2 = sigmoid(Z2)
    ### END CODE HERE ###

Comment: i am implementing neural network and this A! component hai tanh function throwing error